# How would I match data in one column based on data from 2 or more columns

Tags: sql, string, db2

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to do this so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

So the data in the excel file looks like so:

```
Work Title   | Composers/Authors
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACIDS ROCKS  | BARLOW/FOSTER
ABOVE CLOUDS | JEFF BECK,CYNDI LAUPER,JED LEIBER
```

and the data in DB is similiar as in the authors could also be full names or just last names, but they are divided.

Now I would like to match that data with the data in the DB which for example looks like:

```
Work Title   | Composers/Authors
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACIDS ROCKS  | DARREN JAMES BARLOW
ACIDS ROCKS  | FOSTER
```

The desired outcome in this situation would be for these two works to match (value returned could be an ID that is tied to the title in the DB), but if the work doesn't for example contain the record with "FOSTER" then the two works shouldn't match.

The titles should match 100% (so if for example the title is THE ACIDS ROCKS it wouldn't match) and the authors should contain only the last name or it would probably be pretty tough to match them exact based on the data given.

Hope that this makes it clear.

EDIT:

After looking at the data some more and trying to compile it in such a way to be easier it should now look like so:

Data in DB

```
Work Title   | Composers/Authors
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACIDS ROCKS  | DARREN JAMES BARLOW
ACIDS ROCKS  | FOSTER
```

Data in excel table

```
Work Title   | Composers/Authors
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACIDS ROCKS  | FOSTER
ACIDS ROCKS  | DARREN JAMES BARLOW
```

So to make things simple I would only need the data to be 100% same so if the title matches (in this case ACIDS ROCKS) then the query should check if the authors are the same (in this case they are but not in the same order). I'm having problems with making it check every row individually. 
The desired output here would be for the works to match since they have the same title and authors but if for example the DB data would look like

```
Work Title   | Composers/Authors
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACIDS ROCKS  | DARREN JAMES BARLOW
ACIDS ROCKS  | MARK FOSTER
```

then it shouldn't match. Even if FOSTER was missing or we have an additional author in the DB then it shouldn't match (not sure how tough it is to restrict this)

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: @SimonN DB2, but I am able to export the data and import into another DB or even use some code to do this (I'm asking for any way to do this since I can't think of any at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following as is, if your Db2 is for Linux, Unix and Windows.
You may uncomment the commented out row and comment out the row above it to check the difference.

```
WITH 
  EXCEL_TABLE (Title, Author) AS
(
VALUES
  ('ACIDS ROCKS', 'FOSTER')
, ('ACIDS ROCKS', 'DARREN JAMES BARLOW')
)
, DB_TABLE (Title, Author) AS
(
VALUES
  ('ACIDS ROCKS', 'DARREN JAMES BARLOW')
, ('ACIDS ROCKS', 'FOSTER')
--, ('ACIDS ROCKS', 'MARK FOSTER')
)
SELECT E.Title, E.Authors
FROM
(
SELECT Title, LISTAGG(Author, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Author) AS Authors
FROM EXCEL_TABLE
GROUP BY Title
) E
JOIN 
(
SELECT Title, LISTAGG(Author, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Author) AS Authors
FROM DB_TABLE
GROUP BY Title
) D ON D.Title = E.Title AND D.Authors = E.Authors;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help but I'm not sure I understand the process you've given.
I'm not sure it would work like that since I've checked and it seems some records are name first last name second and some our the other way around so it's not really 100% right.
I've asked around for some help and someone told me if I delimit the data I could use 2 loops that circle around and check every author individually and it would work like that.

So to summarize the data would essentially be the same in both tables but for every work title it would need to match all the authors. Is this possible?

Comment: First of all you must provide **exact** rules for name matching. If the last name is not always the last, then it’s impossible to do such a comparison, since JAMES can be both first and last names. `JAMES  BROWN, DAVID JAMES, SMITH JAMES`. It’s possible to match names knowing that the last name is always last, but how to do this in the case above?

Comment: My mistake for not giving enough info sorry. I was thinking that we make the data the same as in the DB so it would be 

`ACIDS ROCKS | BARLOW

 ACIDS ROCKS | FOSTER` 
but in the DB it would be the other way around so

`ACIDS ROCKS | FOSTER

 ACIDS ROCKS | BARLOW`
I don't have a issue with first and last names since I will be matching them exactly but I have an issue as I'm not sure how to check every row individually, what I mean is it would need to check every row in the DB with ACIDS ROCKS for it to find barlow and then go to the next. I guess I misworded myself earlier.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand you. Let’s make it simpler: edit your question and provide the contents of both tables and the result desired in a table form. I believe, that the solution provided at the moment matches the data in the question. If not, then provide the result desired on this data.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was miswording myself before. I agree that your solution is right with my given information at the time but it's not what I need. I've edited the question and hope this clarifies it.
Again sorry for the trouble, I'm just new to stack overflow and sql in general..

Comment: Okay I think you got it, at first it only gave me back `ACIDS ROCKS | DARREN JAMES BARLOW` and I thought it only matched that row but with the uncommented row it doesn't match so it's right.
Just to make sure I understand, you aggregate both rows with a comma and sort them alphabetically so they are both the same if the authors match and then just return the records where the authors match, right?